# How can this error be possible in this code - error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

This is how i call that error given function

```
    var CrawlPage = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return crawlPage(srNewCrawledUrl);
});

var GetLinks = CrawlPage.ContinueWith(resultTask =>
{
    if (CrawlPage.Result == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return ReturnLinks(CrawlPage.Result, srNewCrawledUrl, srNewCrawledPageId);
    }

});
```

This is the error i really don't understand how is that possible. I am using local assigned variables so variables should be thread safe for all threads. Am i incorrect ?

this is the error image : [image]

Comment: Can you post the *complete* stack trace?

Comment: how do i get complete stack trace ?

Comment: Where does it error, and where are srNewCrawledUrl and srNewCrawledPageId declared, used and assigned? In particular, is there a loop?

Comment: Marc Gravell check here : http://pastebin.com/VqGEmPcy  and i suppose you already looked the image. it shows the error.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Click "View Detail..." on the dialog in the image.

Comment: vcsjones it does not show it since it is multithreaded. another thread would already being overridden it i suppose.

Comment: what it shows is when i click view : {Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.}

Comment: ok i found the cause. it is definitely because of file is pdf how to solve problem ? check this image : http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/3953/definitely.png

Comment: PDF != HTML.  You probably want a PDF library.

Comment: SLaks that is correct. But htmlagilitypack does not recognize it as file. How can i determine whether a url is document or crawlable page like html or aspx or php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you better validate InnerHtml is null or not before calling

```
var GetLinks = CrawlPage.ContinueWith(resultTask =>
{
    if (CrawlPage.Result == null || CrawlPage.Result.DocumentNode == null ||  CrawlPage.Result.DocumentNode.InnerHtml == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return ReturnLinks(CrawlPage.Result, srNewCrawledUrl, srNewCrawledPageId);
    }

});
```

Or check this on ReturnLinks method

Comment: hello. instead of this aren't there a way to determine whether url is file or not. that would be a lot better. i would simply ignore file urls.

Comment: also this would still give error because that is simply what i am doing. i suppose there is a bug in microsoft visual studio. because when i try to check whether inner html is null or not it throws null exception.  check this image it will explain more : http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/3953/definitely.png when a file is crawled it gives error.

Comment: the correct answer is those methods has inner methods and those are throwing errors.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using local assigned variables so variables should be thread safe for all threads. Am i incorrect ?

The fact that you are making a reference local does not mean that the object this reference points to suddenly becomes local. Other thread (not shown in your question?) might still be mutating the `HtmlDocument` object at just the wrong moment (between `hdDoc.DocumentNode != null` and `hdDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml != null`).

Comment: it is local variable. how could another thread can access it can you please explain. thanks.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG The `hdDoc` is local, but it is assigned from `Doc` which is a `ReturnLinks` method parameter and I don't know where it came from or what other thread might be using it. In other words, just because `HtmlDocument` object is referenced from the local reference in one thread does not mean it is not also referenced from some other reference in some other thread. It is your responsibility to ensure this is not the case or that the access to that object is properly serialized through locking.

Comment: ok i got your point. but this is not the issue here because problem arises when a non html document loaded. but thanks.